# Can a $0$-dimensional analytic subset of a compact complex variety has infinite many points?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex variety and $A$ the $0$-dimensional  analytic subset of $X$.

> **Question**: **Can $A$ has infinite many points?**

Clues: By the definition of complex spaces and analytic subsets, we can only consider the $0$-dimensional  analytic subset of a **local model** of $X$, since finite many local models can cover $X$. The local model of $X$ may be  $\mathbb{C}^n$ or a  domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$. However $\mathbb{C}^n$ or a  domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$ **may contains a $0$-dimensional  analytic subset containing infinite many points.** e.g., $\mathbb{P}^1=\mathbb{C}^1\cup\{\infty\}$.

**Definition**: A complex **analytic set**  in $X$ is a set which can be defined locally by finitely many holomorphic equations.

Comment: Clarification needed: is the definition: for all $a\in A$, there is an open set $U \subset X$ and analytic functions $f_U : U\to \mathbb C$ so that $A\cap U = f_U^{-1}(0)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar  Yes, for any  $a\in A$, there is an open neighbourhood $U_a$ of $a$  such that $A\cap U_a=\cap_i f_i^{-1}(0)$  with $f_i$ analytic functions on $ U_a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $A$ could be infinite. For example, let $X = \mathbb P^1 = \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ and consider
$$A=\{1, 2, \cdots, n, \cdots\}.$$
Then for all $n\in A$, let $U_n = B(n, 1)$ and $f_n = z-n$. Then $A\cap U_n = \{ n\} = f_n^{-1} (0)$.

**Remark** Following Huybrechts, he defines (1) an **analytic subset** $A$ of an open subset $U$ in $\mathbb C^n$, and (2) an **analytic subvariety** of a complex manifold $X$. When $X = U$, both definition agrees. Hence I cited only the latter one.

**Definition** Let $X$ be a complex manifold. A closed subset $Y$ of $X$ is called an *analytic subvariety* if for each $y\in Y$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $y$ so that $Y\cap U$ is the zero set of finitely many holomorphic functions $f_1, \cdots, f_k \in \mathscr O(U)$.

The closedness assumption is essential here. $A$ constructed above is not is closed in $\mathbb P^1$.

If we further assume that $A$ is closed, then $A$ is indeed finite: let $a\in A$. Then there is an open neighborhood $U$ so that $A\cap U$ is the zero set of $f_1, \cdots, f_k$. Now take a smaller neighborhood $V$ of $x$ compactly contained in $U$. Then $A\cap V$ must be finite (if not, it has a limit point, then $f_i$ must be zero functions, which contradicts that $A$ has dimension zero).

Thus, by choosing an even smaller $W$, we have $A\cap W = \{a\}$. Thus $A$ is an discrete set in $X$. Since $X$ is compact, $A$ is finite.

Comment: Thank you. On a compact Riemann surface, a divisor is usually denoted by $D:=\Sigma_{i\in I} m_i D_i$ with $|I|<\infty$. So  I always wondered if we might be missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked about the definition. I just checked Huybrechts and will say a bit more. @LelongWang

Comment: Yes, the closed assumption for analytic set is very important. Thank you very much, still expect your further answer.

Comment: @LelongWang please see the edit.

Comment: Great answer...

Comment: An  supplement:  the decomposition of a analytic set  into irreducible components is locally finite, and $0$-dimensional irreducible component must be a isolated point.