# Is a $0$-dimensional analytic subvariety of a compact manifold finite?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, complex-geometry

I was looking at this question: [Can a $0$-dimensional analytic subset of a compact complex variety has infinite many points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272863/can-a-0-dimensional-analytic-subset-of-a-compact-complex-variety-has-infinite). The answer says that the answer to my title question is yes, but appears to only prove it when $M=\mathbb{P}^1$. I was wondering how to prove it in the general case, if it is actually true. Here are the definitions I am using.

Definition of subvariety and dimension: Let $M$ be a complex manifold and $V\subset M$ a closed subset. Then $V$ is called an analytic subvariety of $M$ if for all $p\in V$, there is an open neighbourhood $U\subset M$ of $p$ such that
$$U\cap V=Z(f_1,\dots,f_n)=\{x\in U\ :\ f_1(x)=\dots=f_n(x)=0\}$$
where each $f_i\in\mathcal{O}(U)$. The dimension of $V$ is the largest integer $k$ such that there is a neighbourhood $U\subset M$ such that $U\cap V$ is a complex manifold of dimension $k$.

Actual statement I would like to prove/disprove: Let $V\subset M$ be a $0$-dimensional analytic subvariety of a compact complex manifold $M$. Then $V$ is finite.

Comment: Note that your definition of an analytic subset is genuinely different from the one in the link. With your definition, it is a nice exercise to show that a 0-dimensional analytic subvariety of a  compact complex manifold is finite.